# Why can protected attributes be accessed by other classes of the same package

Tags: java, visibility, keyword, protected

Why do protected attributes in a Java class can be accessed by the other classes of the same package ?

I thought it was only accessible through inheritance.

**A.java**

```
package abc;
class A {
    protected int attr1;
}
```

**B.java**

```
package abc;
class B {
    B() {
        A obj = new A();
        obj.attr1 = 2;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        B obj2 = new B();
    }
}
```

Comment: What you're asking is why they have the `private` visibility modifier. `protected` is for classes in the same package.

Comment: @DrewKennedy No. The default visibility (i.e. no `private`, no `public`, no `protected`) is package-private. `protected` means (AFAIK) only subclasses have access to it. It is not package-private.

Comment: @newbiedoodle Protected doesn't mean only subclasses have access to it.

Comment: @peter.petrov Yeah, just looked it up. It's just that no class outside the package can get it.

Comment: @newbiedoodle uhh, nowhere was the default visibility modifier mentioned, but thanks?

Comment: @DrewKennedy I was confused, and thought you were saying that it was *only* visible to the same package, which is a pretty easy conclusion to draw from your comment. That's otherwise known as the 'default visibility', since you get it by not putting any keyword in front of the class.

Comment: @newbiedoodle no worries. I was just surprised about your comment haha. I was just saying that methods or fields that have the `protected` modifier are only available to classes of the package they are contained in. :)

Comment: @DrewKennedy They are also available to any subclasses of the class you're defining.

Comment: The reason is most likely that if it worked that way, and you wanted to allow access to the package *and* to subclasses, you would have to resort to `public`, in which case encapsulation would suffer. The way it has been designed makes the access modifiers increasingly wider, as shown clearly in [this chart](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33627846/276052).

Answer (score 1):

Because that was the decision of the language creators.

Methods/fields with the protected access modifier are accessible
by both classes from **the same package** as the class defining them,
as well as by **subclasses** of the class defining them. And of course,
they are also accessible by **the defining class** itself.

Comment: How did they justify this behavior ?

Comment: You should ask them really. It's hard to tell, it's just a design decision. See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13309609/why-protected-can-be-access-in-same-package-without-inheritance-in-java

Answer (score 1):

You should think about it this way: `protected` is a kind of *public* access level. Protected members are a part of public API in classes designed for extension. It would make no sense for a member accessible to the API client to be inaccessible to the API implementation, especially at a place where another member with default access level (which is non-public) is accessible.